# Can I assign my own randomized Job ID to Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I am using Sidekiq to schedule some tasks based on a schedule that the user provides. However, if the user changes the schedule, I want to be able to simply update the old schedule with the new one.

**Suggestion one**

I saw a suggestion to just find the old job with `Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find_job(job_id)`, but I am trying to avoid having to create a new model just to simply store the job ID and the task.

**Suggestion two**

Another suggestion I saw was to just have the worker check if the time of the task matches the current time, but that won't work because if the server is offline, it won't process jobs when it returns back online because the time of those delayed jobs won't match the current time.

If I could assign my own job ID, like a hex version of the job name or a padded version of the task ID, then I could easily avoid having to create a new model to store the job IDs. So when the user reschedules a task, then it would be a lot easier.

**Other thoughts**

Maybe if I could check the job's `at` attribute and match that with the task, that may work, but I'm not sure how to access that attribute from within the worker without knowing the job ID.

*Edit*

I just tried to pull the current job's `at` attribute, but it looks like once the job kicks off, it doesn't exist anymore in `Sidekiq::ScheduledSet`, so there's no matching *this* job's time with Task's time from what it seems like.

Answer (score 0):

> *I am using Sidekiq to schedule some tasks based on a schedule that the user provides...*

There's an extension for that. [Sidekiq-Scheduler](https://github.com/Moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) gives you a cron-like schedule configuration file. Then you can alter the schedule as you see fit. This seems like the best option as it avoids having to write your own scheduler interface.

> *Can I assign my own randomized Job ID to Sidekiq?*

Yes, though it's undocumented. You can give [`Sidekiq::Client.push`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq%2FClient:push) a `jid` attribute.

```
Sidekiq::Client.push('class' => MyWorker, 'args' => [1, 2, 3], 'jid' => ... )
```

This is not a good way to solve your problem. It's relying on an undocumented feature. And it invites collisions with normal Sidekiq IDs.

> *Maybe if I could check the job's at attribute and match that with the task, that may work, but I'm not sure how to access that attribute from within the worker without knowing the job ID.*

This sounds very error prone. You'd have to store the timestamp in a model anyway. Better to store the job ID in the first place.

> *I am trying to avoid having to create a new model just to simply store the job ID and the task.*

Storing things in models is what Rails does *really well*. This would seem to be the way to go. It will take a trivial amount of coding, database storage, and processing. You should have a model, view, and controller for your scheduled jobs anyway else how will you create scheduled jobs and view your schedule?

However, the [Sidekiq docs notes](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mperham/sidekiq/Sidekiq/JobSet#find_job-instance_method) that `find_job` is "*a slow, inefficient operation. Do not use under normal conditions. Sidekiq Pro contains a faster version.*" This is because it has to iterate through all jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where I had to reschedule jobs based on updates from the User. It is actually pretty slow and complicated.

It's simpler to not reschedule, but instead make the old queued tasks no-ops (no operations) and then queue up the new tasks.

This is basically defined by the logic within the task. You'd have to know that the user updated their schedule somehow and check that within the old jobs and based on some if-check, not go through with the job.